# How to perform if statement only at first call of function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if statement in a function. How to perform if statement only at first call of function?

Comment: Use a boolean flag to set that you already used that function ad if true skip the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this

```
var notFirstRun = false;
function myFunction(){
    if (notFirstRun) return; // this will "exit" the function
    else notFirstRun = true;

    if (foo == bar){ // your if statement
       // somecode
    }
    // rest of the function
}
```

or event more scoped:

```
var myFunction = (function(notFirstRun) {
    return function() {
        if (notFirstRun) return; // this will "exit" the function
        else notFirstRun = true;

        if (foo == bar) { // your if statement
            // somecode
        }
        // rest of the function
    }
})();
```

Comment: Better store that boolean as property of the function like `myFunction.hasBeenCalled = true`

Comment: @JanDvorak because it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Not polluting the rest of the application with function specifics.

Comment: nice simple solution for keeping control of function execution, thanks!